# Problem sharing link on twitter from my website2

Tags: twitter, sharing

Hey, I have a problem sharing a link on twitter:

data-url="http://ipofmywebsite/mypage/?some_id=276&some_name=b+a"

As I put this in data-url twitter says it's a bad url, is that because my website has an ip instead of a true url? Or there is something wrong in the data-url field?

Thanks

Comment: Fist of all: what language you use to build this url? Maybe you have to encode the url or something. Maybe the ip thing is bad too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like IPs [don't currently work](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2088) with the tweet button. You can post what IP is not working and hopefully Twitter's next release will fix any issues. You could also have a URL shortener wrap the IP as a work around.